# Pandas NaN value causing trouble when change values depending on other columns

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

why do pandas NaN values sometime typed as numpy.float64, and sometimes float?
This is so confusing when I want to use function and change values in a dataframe depending on other columns

example:

```
   A    B    C
0  1  NaN    d
1  2    a    s
2  2    b    s
3  3    c  NaN
```

I have a def to change value of column C

```
def change_val(df):
    if df.A==1 and df.B==np.nan:
        return df.C
    else:
        return df.B
```

Then I apply this function onto column C

```
df['C']=df.apply(lambda x: change_val(x),axis=1)
```

Things go wrong on `df.B==np.nan`, how do I correctly express this please?

Desired result:

```
   A    B    C
0  1  NaN    d
1  2    a    a
2  2    b    b
3  3    c    c
```

Comment: if df.A==1 and df.B==np.nan:
->
if df.A==1 and pd.isnull(df.B):

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) or [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html), for check missing values is used special function [`Series.isna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isna.html):

```
mask = (df.A==1) & (df.B.isna())
#oldier pandas versions
#mask = (df.A==1) & (df.B.isnull())
df['C'] = np.where(mask, df.C, df.B)
```

Or:

```
df.loc[~mask, 'C'] = df.B
```

---

```
print (df)
   A    B  C
0  1  NaN  d
1  2    a  a
2  2    b  b
3  3    c  c
```

For more information about working with missing data check [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/missing_data.html#values-considered-missing).

Answer (score 0):

```
def change_val(df):
    if df.A==1 and pd.isnull(df.B):
        return df.C
    else:
        return df.B
```

NaN is no value will not be equal to any value, not even Nan itself, so use isnull()/isna()